# Как предотвратить скрытие выпадающего меню

Tags: javascript, css3, bootstrap, tab, dropdown

*Используется Bootdtrap 3.3.7 + JQuery 3.1.1*

***Ситуация:***
По клику на пункт меню (dropdown), выплывает панель с вкладками (tabs).
После клика по кладке или на панели - панель закрывается.

*Чтобы не закрывалась сделал:*

```
$('.dropdown-menu, .mega-dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Теперь при клике по вкладкам или по панели - панель не скрывается, но и вкладки не работыют.

***Задача:***
Как сделать так, чтобы и вкладки работали и панель не закрывалась при клике по элементам панели?

[Песочница](http://codepen.io/drakulitka/pen/XMaGBb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот эти варианты:

**Первый вариант:**

```
$('.dropdown-menu a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()        
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

[Песочница](http://codepen.io/YozhEzhi/pen/GWvaOo?editors=1010)

**Второй вариант:**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', '.nav-tabs', function() {
    // set a special class on the '.dropdown' element
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').addClass('dontClose');
})

$('.mega-dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('dontClose')) e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('dontClose');
});
```

[Песочница](http://codepen.io/YozhEzhi/pen/evEaEK?editors=1010).

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525440/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-with-tabs-inside) решения с пояснениями. Полагаю, что перевод не потребуется.

Comment: Спасибо, оба варианта работают!!!